# Meaning of attic faith

Tags: meaning

Today, while reading my English-Vietnamese dictionary, I came across a relatively new phrase, "attic faith", which is translated into Vietnamese as "niềm tin không thể bị lay chuyển".

As I looked it up, I only found 4 related results:

http://www.whatdoesthatmean.com/dictionary/A/attic-faith.html

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Attic_faith

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Attic+faith

http://www.yourdictionary.com/attic-faith

All of them have the same definition: unshakeable faith or inviolable faith. However, as a selective learner, I do not usually believe something without questioning its reliability. I also looked up the word "attic" in the OED but there is no definition of it being "unshakeable" or "inviolable". Consequently, it made me doubt the existence of the phrase "attic faith".

I would like to know if it is a real phrase and its meaning is such.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "a real phrase"?  If you can find it in the dictionary then that would seem to make it "real".  Do you actually mean "commonly used" or something similar?

Comment: The answers suggest that "attic" needs to be capitalized.

Comment: Interesting. I would have naively guessed it meant the faith of someone who could only pray in the attic of a house, because of religious persecution.

Comment: This folks, is "how" you ask a question about the meaning of a word or phrase.

Comment: @Max Williams: Sorry, what I actually meant was "commonly used". Sometimes I have difficulty in conveying my idea and so I may unknowingly use a wrong word.

Comment: @200_success: Sorry about that. The phrase in my dictionary wasn't capitalized.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The term ***Attic faith*** certainly seems to be rare, but not new.  Ngram records 0 instances, but online sources attest to [a definition in Webster's 1913 dictionary](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Attic%20faith):

> inviolable faith

This same dictionary also lists several related terms, and references them in [its adjectival definition of ***Attic***](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Attic), which was new to me:

> a.    1.  Of or pertaining to Attica, in Greece, or to Athens, its principal city; marked by such qualities as were characteristic of the Athenians; classical; refined.
>
> Attic base
>   (Arch.) a peculiar form of molded base for a column or pilaster, described by Vitruvius, applied under the Roman Empire to the Ionic and Corinthian and "Roman Doric" orders, and imitated by the architects of the Renaissance.
>
> Attic faith
>   inviolable faith.
>
> Attic purity
>   special purity of language.
>
> Attic salt
>   a poignant, delicate wit, peculiar to the Athenians.
>
> Attic story
>   See Attic, n.
>
> Attic style
>   a style pure and elegant.

You go on to say,

> I would like to know if it is a real phrase and its meaning is such.

It apparently is a "real phrase", in the sense that multiple authorities attest to it.  I personally attribute more authority to Webster's than to the sources you listed, but any way around, multiple attestations are strong evidence.  On the other hand, if by "real phrase" you mean do people actually say or write that phrase in modern English, then no.  I never saw or heard it before today.

Comment: I had never actually hear 'attic faith', but if I had I should have presumed it meant 'the religion followed by the ancient Athenians'.

Comment: I've also never heard or seen the phrase, but when seeing this question I guessed it meant "faith kept in the attic": faith in theory only but not in practice.

Comment: I have heard it, twenty years ago when I was a child.  I presumed its meaning as @jd18 was saying.  I thought it meant weak faith, that people only bother to get out of the attic on occasion (like holiday decorations).  So, this web page was interesting, teaching me that the phrase actually meant the exact opposite of what I understood.  Still, I join the chorus of people proclaiming that this phrase seems to be exceedingly rare among native speakers of American English.  It is so rare, that it is prone to be misunderstood (as dj18 and I did), so it is not safe to use without explanation.

Comment: It was perfectly safe to use it when everyone with more than an elementary education had studied classical languages. The "classical Greek" learned by beginners is essentially Attic Greek, i.e. the language of Athens in the 4th and 5th centuries BCE, the native language of Plato, Aristotle, etc, and the version of Greek used by the Romans. (The Greek Empire used a different dialect, Koine Greek or "common Greek" - with a similar relation to Attic Greek as "English as a Foreign Language" has to "Formal English").

Comment: @alephzero Your comment looks Greek to me.  (sorry, bad joke.)  "when everyone with more than an elementary education had studied" such "languages"...  do you really think that resembles today?  (in America...  I know Europeans are more prone to be multi-lingualists)

Comment: @alephzero The connection between "Attic Greek" and "inviolable faith" isn't obvious IMO. Perhaps I'm supposed to equate "Attic" with "especially good", e.g. an "Attic horse" would be a great horse?

Comment: alephzero is saying that the study of ancient Greece, its culture and language was more common in the past (+30 years ago) than today, hence  the term *Attic* would have been more familiar. Attic being related to Athens, is never going to be the first thing that pops up in someone's mind, especially in speech. The clue that the term was not about a storage room under a roof was the capital letter.

Comment: @PellMel: Sorry, I have difficulty in conveying my idea at times. By "real phrase" I mean "commonly used phrase". In other words, "do  do people actually say or write that phrase in modern English". 
Thank you and those who have shed light on my question. I really appreciate all your comments.

Answer (score 15):

It is the case that the Wiktionary entry for [Attic faith](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Attic_faith) shows "Inviolable faith".

But note the capital letter. In that entry, the word *Attic* is also a link:

> **Etymology**
>   From Ancient Greek Ἀττικός ‎(Attikós, “related to Athens”).
>
> **Adjective**
>   Attic ‎(comparative more Attic, superlative most Attic)
>
> 1. Relating to Athenian culture or architecture.
> 2. Marked by the qualities that were characteristic of the Athenians; classical; refined.
> 3. Relating to that dialect of Ancient Greek.

Perhaps the ancient Athenian culture was noted for unshakeable faith.

Answer (score 5):

**You may find the entry from the OED helpful. Note that *Attic* is a reference to *Attica* or its capital Athens:**

> 2. Having characteristics peculiarly Athenian; hence, of literary style, etc.: Marked by simple and refined elegance, pure, classical.
>      Attic salt or Attic wit (Latin sal Atticum): refined, delicate,
>      poignant wit. Attic faith: inviolable faith.
>
> 1633   Battle of Lutzen in Harl. Misc. (Malh.) IV. 185   Written in a
>   stile so attick..that it may well be called the French Tacitus.
>
> 1738   Pope Epil. to Satires ii. 7   While Roman Spirit charms, and
>   Attic Wit.
>
> 1762   L. Sterne Life Tristram Shandy V. iii. 27   Triumph swam in my
>   father's eyes, at the repartee—the Attic salt brought water into them.
>
> 1830   T. Hamilton Cyril Thornton (1845) 49   The true attic
>   pronunciation inculcated in Mrs. Blenkinsop's academy.
>
> 1864   M. Arnold in Cornhill Mag. Aug. 164   Well, but Addison's prose
>   is Attic prose.

Answer (score 4):

I found it used [here in a footnote](https://books.google.fr/books?id=wUGV9L1YaGkC&lpg=PA206&ots=lkO3vjal3Q&dq=attic%20faith%20punic%20faith&pg=PA206#v=onepage&q=attic%20faith%20punic%20faith&f=false) in an edition of *The Satires of Persius and Juvenal*:

> for at one time 'Attic faith' was proverbially as good as 'Punic faith' was bad.

I guess the footnote is referring to this phrase of the text:

> ... nondum Graecis jurare paratis per caput alterius ...

... which I think implies that "faith" in this context means 'can be relied upon to keep their promises', rather than 'religious belief' (see also [The Roman Concept of '*FIDES*'](http://www.csun.edu/~hcfll004/fides.html)).

---

IMO it's so uncommon that it's no longer a "real phrase, commonly used". Even though I had some (slight) acquaintance with Classics I didn't understand that phrase (and I didn't recall having heard or read it before) when you presented it out of context.